# Removing the row from UITableView and updating the section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, header

I am showing some rows into the `UITableView` and the count of the rows in the header of the section, but when i delete the rows then the view looks very weird will deleting with animation. Look into my code if i am missing something.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc]init] autorelease];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(249.0/255.0) green:(249.0/255.0) blue:(249.0/255.0) alpha:1];

    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 100, 15)] autorelease];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.56 green:0.56 blue:0.58 alpha:1.0]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12]];
    label.text = @"SELECTED ACCOUNTS (";

    NSString *numberOfAccounts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li)", (unsigned long)[self->_selectedAccounts count]];

    if([self->_selectedAccounts count])
         label.text = [label.text stringByAppendingString:numberOfAccounts];

    [view addSubview:label];
    [view sizeToFit];
    [label sizeToFit];
    return view;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *selectedAcc = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self->_selectedAccounts];
        [selectedAcc removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self->_selectedAccounts = selectedAcc;
        [self->_MyTableView beginUpdates];
        [self->_MyTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [self->_MyTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self->_MyTableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your if condition:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndexPath.section];
[yourArrayAnswerCount removeObjectAtIndex:myIndexPath.section]; 
[tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:myIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];


    [tableView endUpdates];
```

This will also help you... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am able to delete the row and update the header the only problem with my code is that it is not animating as it should. Lets say i the two lines which delete row and update the header are as below: 

`[self->_MyTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        //[self->_MyTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` so in this case i commented the code which updates my section header, so now the animation of the dletion is good.

Comment: OK. and please read that link in my answer .. that also help you for your problem...

Comment: Yes i am trying to understand from the link you gave.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
[self->_MyTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self->_MyTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

with

```
[self->_MyTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

reloadSections: should imply rowUpdates. This should suffice

Comment: Thanks for the reply yes the way you said i tried but still there is weird animation, which i dont want. Please check my comment on @Suraj Sukale answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete and add rows with animation try this way :-

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

deleteIndexPaths is a array of NSIndexPaths to be deleted from your table.

```
NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
        nil];
```

My be it will help you

Comment: Well deleting the row is working fine from my code, my only concern is to update the title header of the section which will have the count of rows.